# With EE 2.7 can you use a channel form on the front end to create new categories?

Tags: ee2, channel-form

With EE 2.7 can you use a channel form on the front end to create new categories?  Can't quite figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add categories though the channel form, unfortunately. You've got a couple options:

1) It'd be a bit involved, but it's not altogether impossible to write a module that allows categories to be added from the front-end. Just take note of the various tables for categories and what needs to be filled out when added. If you're not familiar with add-on development already, though, this may be a bit challenging.

2) Switch to a tagging addon, such as the free [Tagger from DevDemon](http://www.devdemon.com/tagger). Tagger provides an interface that works with the channel form on the front-end. While tagging isn't exactly the same functionality as categories, in many cases it's pretty seamless to switch over.

Comment: Jeremy thanks for the comment.  I'm an EE novice, but the project that I have in mind, there will be a few times when a user would want to create a new category to upload pdf files to.

Comment: Anytime! I think using Tagger would be the best bet for you then.